# CSS: Two element with one flexing. Prevent wrap.

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to float a image to the right side of a paragraph. It's much harder than I thought.

```
                                  100px
+-------------------------+  +------------+
|                         |  |            |
|                         |  |            |
|   text                  |  |  img       |100px
|                         |  |            |
|                         |  |            |
+-------------------------+  +------------+


<div>
  <p>Some text...</p>
  <img src="url" />
</div>
```

I need the text to flex when I change the viewport. Right now the image wrap when the window get smaller.

```
+--------------------------+ +
|                          | |
|       text               | |
|                          | |
+--------------------------+ |
+----------+                 |
|          |                 |
|  img     |                 |
|          |                 |
|          |                 |
+----------+                 |
                             v
```

I need it to do this:

```
+--------------+ +----------+  +
|              | |          |  |
|              | |   img    |  |
|              | |          |  |
|   text       | |          |  |
|              | +----------+  |
|              |               |
|              |               |
+--------------+               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               v
```

I don't want to use position:absolute on the image. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image before the text:

```
<div>
   <img src="url" />
  <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

working: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmacu/GgPYy/

not: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmacu/gxHNk/